# Extracting maximum value in Soil moisture timeseries and exporting image using Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, time-series, nasa

I have a time series code that shows soil moisture in an area but I want to get the highest moisture obtained during the time period and export it as an image. I have tried but seems like my code is not giving the highest moisture obtained.

This is a link to the code:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d73b58b0ade8eaee2e1a44fbea73873d

```
/// IMPORTING THE FEATURE COLLECTION ///
var points = points.map(function(feature){
  var sample_id = feature.get('Sample_ID');
  return ee.Feature(feature.geometry(), {'id': feature.id()})
    .set('Sample_ID', sample_id);
});

Map.addLayer(points,{color:'green'},'Root Locations');
Map.centerObject(points,10);
print(points);

var points_list = points.toList(points.size());

var keys = points_list.map(function (ele) {

  return ee.Feature(ele).get('id');
  
});

var values = points_list.map(function (ele) {

  return ee.Feature(ele).get('Sample_ID');
  
});

var dict = ee.Dictionary.fromLists(keys, values);



var SM = ee.ImageCollection("NASA_USDA/HSL/SMAP10KM_soil_moisture")
print (SM);


//// Filtering the Image collection 
var filteredSM = SM.filter(ee.Filter.date('2020-09-25','2021-05-30'))
                    .select('ssm')
                    .filter(ee.Filter.bounds(points))

print(filteredSM);

var testPoint = ee.Feature(points.first());

//Map.centerObject(testPoint, 10)


// FETCH THE MAX MEAN KNDVI IMAGE FROM THE WITH_KNDVI COLLECTION
var maxSSM_Mean = filteredSM.reduceColumns({
  reducer: ee.Reducer.max(), selectors: ['ssm']});
var maxSSM_MeanImg = filteredSM.filter(
  ee.Filter.eq('ssm', maxSSM_Mean.get('max'))).first();
print('Mean max SSM image', maxSSM_MeanImg);

/// TIMESERIES CHART FOR SINGLE LOCATION ///
var chart = ui.Chart.image.series({
    imageCollection: filteredSM.select('ssm'),
    region: testPoint.geometry()
    }).setOptions({
      interpolateNulls: true,
      lineWidth: 1,
      pointSize: 3,
      title: 'Soil Moisture for single location',
      vAxis: {title: 'SSM'},
      hAxis: {title: 'Date', format: 'YYYY-MMM', gridlines: {count: 12}}
    })
print(chart)


var chart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion({
    imageCollection: filteredSM.select('ssm'),
    regions: points,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean()
})
print(chart)


//// EXPORTING MULTIPLE LOCATION TIMESERIES ///
Export.table.toDrive({
    collection: filteredSM,
    description: 'Multiple_Locations_SSM_time_series',
    folder: 'earthengine',
    fileNamePrefix: 'SSM_time_series_multiple',
    fileFormat: 'CSV'
})

var Vis = {
  min: 0.0,
  max: 28.0,
  palette: ['0300ff', '418504', 'efff07', 'efff07', 'ff0303'],
};

Map.addLayer(filteredSM.median(),Vis,'SM')

/// displaying soil moisture series for one pixel
var image = filteredSM.toBands().clip(Etosha);

Map.addLayer(image,{},'SM_Timeseries')

Export.image.toDrive({
  image: maxSSM_MeanImg.select('ssm'),
  description: 'Soil_Moisture',
  scale: 10000,
  region: Etosha,
  folder: 'GEE',
  crs: 'EPSG:4326',
  });
```

Comment: Why do you think the image is not showing the highest moisture?

Comment: because the image when Exported to ArcMap layer value shows a range of low 2.1231 and a high 3.000 whilst the Timeseries shows the highest value obtained is 22.763 during the time period.